# How to send res.render string parameter and render it as HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to send html string as a `res.render()` parameter and render it as html in the client-side. How do I get the browser to recognize it as html instead of just as a string? Can this be done?

home.hbs

```html
<div id="results">
  {{#each results}}
    <p>{{this}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

server.js

```
app.get('\', (req,res) => {
  let results = ['<mark>This</mark> is highlighted.']
  res.render('home', {results: results});
})
```

In my webpage, I want it to look like a paragraph where the word 'This' is highlighted (because of `<mark>`) but instead it shows up as `<mark>This</mark> is highlighted.` where `This` is not highlighted and the mark tags are plain text.

Comment: you could do it by using ejs template : https://ejs.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "triple-stash" to cancel html escape functionality.
https://handlebars-lang.github.io/docs/guide/#html-escaping